# Java - else if and else without if?

Tags: java, comments, if-statement

Hey so i had this Java program working before i added comments but now i am getting an error with the the else if and else statements saying they are without an if, are the comments interfering with how the if statement is read? Any help is much appreciated.

```
/**
  * A class that takes 2 different times in military time as input and 
  * outputs the difference in hours and minutes.
  *
  * @author Name
  */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment1Q3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the first time: ");
    int fTime = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the second time: ");
    int lTime = in.nextInt();
    int tDifference = Math.abs(fTime - lTime);//Calculates the absolute difference.
    String strTDiff = String.valueOf(tDifference);//Converts the value to a String.
    int length = strTDiff.length();//Obtains the length of the value.
    String hours = "";//Declares the values to be initialized in the if statement.
    String minutes = "";
    if (length == 4)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);/**If the number of digits is 4, the first
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);*two are the hour.
     }                                      */
    else if (length == 3)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);/**If the number of digits is 3, the first
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(1, 3);*one is the hour.
    }                                      */
    else
    {
        hours = ("0");                   /**If the number of digits is not 4 or  3,
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);*the value is less than 1 hour.
    }                                      */
    System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can see that from the highlighting.

Comment: And it certainly isn't doing what you want with the `minutes` calculations. Block comments are just that, a block, and anything between `/*` and `*/` is "invisible" to the compiler.

Comment: oh wow how did i miss that i get it now thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's because the `}` just before your last `else` is commented between `/*` and `*/`.

The colors of any proper code editor should make it evident, just as it is in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have commented  the closing curly bracket for if,else and elseif.Remove it

Answer (score 1):

As you can clearly see directly here on the website (the syntax highlighting) you have indeed commented out some of these: `}`. Three if I'm not mistaken. That's what's causing the error. You've also commented out three lines of code (that might have been intentional, but I thought I'd mention it). I'd suggest that you use some IDE. I myself use Eclipse for Java.

You can comment out single lines using double slash, `//`, in Java (everything to the right of the double slashes will be commented out)

Answer (score 1):

You have the closing bracket commented out in all of your if, else if, and else statements

```
if (length == 4)
{
    hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);/**If the number of digits is 4, the first
    minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);*two are the hour.
}                                      */
```

It looks like you don't know exactly how block comments work. You're assuming that the comments only apply to text coming after the `*` character on each line. In reality, all characters, including new lines and carriage returns, are commented out until it reaches a `*/`.
You probably want to change your code so that it looks like this for each entry:

```
if (length == 4)
{
    /* If the number of digits is 4, the first
     * two are the hour.
     */
    hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);
    minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);
}
```

It may be helpful to note that the star on the second line of the comment is not necessary. E.g.:

```
/* If the number of digits is 4, the first
   two are the hour.
 */
```

This is still a valid block comment. (Although not as readable)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your `*/` (closing the comment) is on the same line as the `}` (closing the `if` block), thus making it part of the comment. It also comments out some code that I assume you want to be executed.

The block comment markers `/*` and `*/` make everything between them into comments, including line breaks. The asterisks on each new line in the comments at the beginning of your code are there just for style and alignment, and have no actual significance.

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted comment in a way that your most of the programming is enclosed into that comment. Just remove your comments and then compile the program.
You should rather use `BlueJ` or `Net Beans` which will show you with its different color schemes that what is wrong with your programming pattern.